# Internet Explorer 11 handling jQuery differently depending on whether the developer tools are open

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a jQuery $.ajax POST that only fires on IE11 if the developer tools are open. It works fine on Chrome and Edge. The code that fires it is as follows:

```
$(".edit").click(function () {
        data = "id=" + $(this).attr("cart") + "&num=" + $("input.num").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Cart")',
            data: data,
            type: "POST"
        }).done(location.reload());
    });
```

Another POST on another page works regardless. The following code creates it:

```
$(".add").click(function () {
        var nums = [
            $(this).attr("item_id"),
            $(this).attr("quote_id"),
            $(this).attr("quantity_amount"),
            $(this).attr("cus_no")
        ]
        data = $.validator.format("item_id={0}&quote_id={1}&quantity_amount={2}&cus_no={3}", nums);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Add","Cart")',
            data: data,
            type: "POST"
        });
    });
```

I am completely lost.

Comment: You can be sure that the issue has nothing to do with opening Developer Tools or not, and I doubt the problem is IE, FF... or who knows what. Try to clear browser's cache...

Comment: For one thing...always use `var`. You are declaring `data` globally. Any form tags involved in this? Use error handlers. Need more feedback on what is or isn't happening

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I did so. The behavior still persists, working with tools open and failing with them closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing a couple of things wrong, which may be creating the issue

firstly use `var data = somethinghere` instead of `data = somethinghere`

secondly, in the **done** method of first sample, use it like

```
.done(function () { window.location.reload() });
```

instead of

```
.done(location.reload());
```

one more thing, remember it as a rule, always use var if declaring new variables, also use semi-colons (add a semi-colon at the end of num array there). Such bizarre things happen in IE because it performs stricter validations.

Comment: I have no idea why that stricter validation was only a problem with the developer tools hidden, but the issue seems to be gone. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's one of the weirdest behaviors of IE :) welcome